# How to return a month name using a Javascript if function

Tags: javascript, if-statement

I am a very new to JS, and had a simple question, How can I get my code below to return the month name, in this case December?

Thank you.

```
window.onload = function() {
    var monthName = getMonth(12);   
    document.getElementById("months").innerHTML = getMonth(month);
};

function getMonth(month) {
    var monthName;
    if (month === 12) {
}
    return monthName;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/priswiz/kU8Js/

Comment: Why would you need to use `if`? Even if you don't know about Arrays, you should use `switch` instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A few things:

- You're never setting the `monthName` variable equal to anything in the `getMonth` function.
- Your logic in the `onload` is was a bit screwy.
- You need your `div` to have an ID of "months", not a class.

Here a working version of your code based on your JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/kU8Js/2/

```
window.onload = function() {
    document.getElementById("months").innerHTML = getMonth(12);   
};

function getMonth(month) {
    var monthName;
    if (month === 12) {
        monthName = "December";
    }
    return monthName;
}
```

With that said, Ellochka Cannibal has a much better method of doing it. But there you go.

Answer (score 3):

```
function getMonth(monthNumber) {
    var monthNames = [ "January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June",
    "July", "August", "September", "October", "November", "December" ];

    return monthNames[monthNumber-1];
}
```

Comment: Wouldn't that be: `monthName=monthNames[12]` - beat me to it!

Comment: @RobG is there any speed ( or other ) benefit to using `--var`? I've used them in the past but stopped because they ended up confusing me :D not that speed is a factor here

Comment: It's just a bit neater and leverages a language feature. You can also do something like: `return ['January', … 'December'][--monthNumber];` or elide the first value and not decrement the month number: `return [,'January', … 'December'][monthNumber];`, but use whatever works best for you.

Answer (score 1):

You should define an array of months then use it as a map between month no and name.

```
var months = new Array( "January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June", "July", "August", "September", "October", "November", "December");
window.onload = function() {
     var monthName = getMonth(12);  

$(".months").html(monthName)   ;
};

function getMonth(monthNo) {

return months[monthNo-1];  //the array start with 0 and month no. start with 1
}
```

He is a running [solution](http://jsfiddle.net/kU8Js/3/)

Answer (score 0):

I would store the names in a map for quick lookup and you can easily extend it:

```
var getMonth = function (num) {
    var m = {
        0: 'Jan', 1: 'Feb', 2: 'Mar',
        3: 'Apr', 4: 'May', 5: 'Jun',
        6: 'Jul', 7: 'Aug', 8: 'Sep',
        9: 'Oct', 10: 'Nov', 11: 'Dec'
    }
    return m[num];
}
```

By the way, here is your corrected jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/kU8Js/4/. You cannot use getElementById with a class.

Comment: You can use `getElementById` if the element has a `class` providing it also has an `id`. (im sure you know this, its just the way you've worded it!)

Comment: Yeah, it was worded funny. Fixed.

Answer (score 0):

Lots of answers here, so why not have a go :D

The following should stop you recreating the `months` array every time you call the function and also keeps it (months array) out of the global name space.

```
var monthName = (function() { 
  var months = ["January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June", "July", "August", "September", "October", "November", "December"];
  return function(month) { 
    return months[month-1]; 
  }
})();
```